# How do I replace all of the specific characters in the string from the lists with the replacement characters?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to replace the "i", "s", and "p" in the string "Mississippi" with the second character of each list in the list below. When replacement is printed by itself, it will replace all of the characters with the character specified, but it will only actually replace the first character that I want to replace in the new string, not all of them. (Ex. Mlsslsslppl instead of Ml$$l$$lzzl) I don't really know where to go from here to fix this problem.

```
def substitutePairs(myString, pairsList):
    for item in myString:
        for separateList in pairsList:
            for char in separateList:
                if item == char:
                    replacement = separateList[1]
                    newString = myString.replace(item, replacement)

    return newString

def main():
    myString = "Mississippi"
    pairsList = [['i', 'l'],['s', '$'],['p', 'z']]
    print(substitutePairs(myString, pairsList))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iteratively apply `replace` to the previous result so that you can accumulate all of the substitutions into one string.  A single loop over `pairs_list` is all you need; `replace` will do the work for you of iterating through `my_string`.

```
>>> def subst_pairs(my_string, pairs_list):
...     for x, y in pairs_list:
...         my_string = my_string.replace(x, y)
...     return my_string
...
>>> subst_pairs("Mississippi", [['i', 'l'],['s', '$'],['p', 'z']])
'Ml$$l$$lzzl'
```

Comment: Note that substitute characters `y` may become substituted themselves if they happen to be an `x` at a later iteration (not sure if that's OP's desired behavior or not).

Comment: I'm speaking in context of their original code, where they're calling `replace` on the original string.  This results in only the *final* replacement being applied -- for *this approach* to work they need to accumulate all of the replacements.  (Lighten up, Francis!)

Answer (score 0):

That **really** looks like a job for `str.translate` instead:

```
>>> 'Mississippi'.translate(str.maketrans('isp', 'l$z'))
'Ml$$l$$lzzl'
```

If you really have such a list (and can't use the above), you can still build the translation table from it:

```
def subst_pairs(my_string, pairs_list):
    return my_string.translate({ord(k): v for k, v in pairs_list})
```

Or:

```
def subst_pairs(my_string, pairs_list):
    return my_string.translate(str.maketrans(*map(''.join, zip(*pairs_list))))
```